# Mounting local filesystem... : Volume was not properly unmounted

Tags: raspbian, boot-issues, fsck

I'm getting this error on Raspbian on boot:

`Mounting local filesystem... FAT-fs (mmcblk0p1): Volume was not properly unmounted. Some data may be corrupt. Please run fsck.`

But when I run `fsck` I only got:

`fsck from util-linux 2.20.1`

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start up your system as normal then unmount the boot partition, check it, optionally correct it, and remount.

> sudo umount /boot           # unmount
>
> sudo fsck /dev/mmcblk0p1    # see what it says
>
> sudo fsck -a /dev/mmcblk0p1 # if happy with suggested corrections
>
> sudo mount /boot            # remount

---

EDITED TO ADD

If the above does not solve the problem you may need to use a tool called dosfsck rather than fsck.

dosfsck is part of the dosfstools package.

> sudo apt-get install dosfstools

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did it and removed a `dirty bit` but another time, during boot I got the same error

Comment: I have a vague memory of having to download a dosfsutils package and use sudo dosfsck to correct a similar error on the SD card.  It was several years ago so I may have misremembered.

Comment: @xPino The package is dosfstools  (sudo apt-get install dosfstools).

Comment: dosfsck worked! Should I/you imporove your question replacing `fsck` with `dosfsck`? Anyway thank you